# Undo and redo on drawing board with Fabric.js and Fabric-brush.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I developed a drawing board with Fabric.js and Fabric-brush.js. While when I add undo and redo functions, they doesn't work. But they can work when I don't refer fabric-brush.js. So how can I make the Spray Brush function with fabric-brush.js and Undo and Redo function together?

Here is its Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Miamiaoke/x68v7kn9/4/

Here is references:
1.https://jsfiddle.net/Fidel90/7kmf3jz2/
2.https://codepen.io/keerotic/pen/yYXeaR

Many thanks.

```
//undo and redo
canvas.on('object:added', function() {
  if (!isRedoing) {
    h = [];
  }
  isRedoing = false;
});

var isRedoing = false;
var h = [];

function undo() {
  if (canvas._objects.length > 0) {
    h.push(canvas._objects.pop());
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
}

function redo() {

  if (h.length > 0) {
    isRedoing = true;
    canvas.add(h.pop());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://github.com/lyzerk/fabric-history

**Importing order**

1. fabric
2. fabric-brush
3. fabric-history

Comment: Thank you for your help! But the fabric-brush.js doesn't work on the demo with the importing order.